# Dynamically binding countdown value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, timer

I am using angularjs timer for "countdown" here is the link http://siddii.github.io/angular-timer/index.html#/timer-with-end-time.
Issue is when I try to bind "end-time" its not working.This is what i am using:

```
<timer end-time=" {{ time }}">{{days}} days, {{hours}} hours, {{minutes}} minutes, {{seconds}} seconds.</timer>
```

In controller:

```
angular.module('timer-demo',['timer']).controller('TimerController',['$scope',  function ($scope){ $scope.time = '1451628000000';});
```

I have also tried:

```
ng-attr-end-time = "{{ time }}"
```

but still no luck.

Also, I want to update timer value on the basis of user select date-time from datepicker.Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could directly use that value without interpolation `{{}}`. Because the directive has used `endTimeAttr: '=endTime',` on [**this line**](https://github.com/siddii/angular-timer/blob/master/dist/angular-timer.js#L16)

```
<timer end-time="time">
   {{days}} days, {{hours}} hours, {{minutes}} minutes, {{seconds}} seconds.
</timer>
```

Comment: Great its work.Thanks..One more thing.How I can change the date like this "09/04/2015 03:31:07 PM" into the format accept by "end-time"..Any idea?

Comment: @user5320720 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: @user5320720 As far as your other question in the comment above is concerned, please ask it in a separate question on this site and you will find you will get a better response than putting in a comment.